# How to set values to a particular key combination in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

When I tried to set a value to a particular key combination, the value was added to all the keys matching the second key. Is this expected behaviour? How do I add to a specific combination?

My code is :

```
results = {
    'mape_train_dummy':[],
    'rmse_train_dummy':[],
    'mape_test_dummy':[],
    'rmse_test_dummy':[],
    
    'mape_train_pinn':[],
    'rmse_train_pinn':[],
    'mape_test_pinn':[],
    'rmse_test_pinn':[],
    
    'y_train_true':[],
    'y_train_pred':[],
    'y_test_true':[],
    'y_test_pred':[],
    'best_model':[],
    
    
    'mape_test_dummy_socs':[],
    'rmse_test_dummy_socs':[],
    'mape_test_pinn_socs':[],
    'rmse_test_pinn_socs':[]
    }
consolidated_results = {}


input_types = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4', 'type5']


for input_type in input_types:
    
    consolidated_results[input_type] = results
    
input_type = input_types[0]
consolidated_results[input_type]['mape_train_dummy'] = 50
```

My expected output was :

```
consolidated_results['type1']['mape_train_dummy']
Out[31]: 50

consolidated_results['type2']['mape_train_dummy']
Out[31]: []
```

But the output:

[image: the output I get]

Why is the value added to all the 'input_types'? How to do this correctly?

Comment: `consolidated_results[input_type] = results` This does not make a COPY of results.  It uses the actual results object.  So your `consolidated_results` dictionary contains five keys, all of which refer to **the same** dictionary, so changing any of them will change all of them, because they are all **the same object**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the dictionary copied using the `=` operator, points to the same object as the original. So if any change is made in the copied dictionary will also reflect in the original dictionary.

To overcome this we can use `copy()` method that returns a shallow copy of the dictionary. When a change is made to the shallow copy, the original dictionary will remain unchanged.

So in your code do,

```
for input_type in input_types:
    consolidated_results[input_type] = results.copy()
```